# Transforming one route value into a different argument on a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I have a fairly simple controller action which takes a string from the route, looks up a guid value from a service.

```
[HttpGet("{externalId}")]
public IActionResult GetInternalId(string externalId)
{
    var internalId = await _externalService.GetInternalId(externalId);
    return internalId == null ? NotFound() : Ok(internalId);
}
```

This is just the simplest demo, the service may return a null in which case its not found, or it might return a valid guid and in which case we return it. This pattern is repeated all over the place with the controller taking the external (string) id and wanting to get the internal (Guid) id before doing more work, so I thought to wrap this up into some sort of filter

```
public class ExternalIdActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly ExternalService _externalService;
    public ExternalIdActionFilter(ExternalService externalService) =>
        _externalService = externalService;

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var externalId = context.RouteData.Values["externalId"]?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(externalId))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            return;
        }

         // Here is the Guid I'm trying to pass to the controller.
        var internalId = await _externalService.GetInternalId(externalId);

        if (internalId== null)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
            return;
        }

        context.RouteData.Values.Add("internalId", internalId);
        await next();
    }
}
```

and applying this to my controller:

```
[HttpGet("{externalId}")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ExternalIdActionFilter))]
public IActionResult GetAccountId(Guid internalId)
{        
    return Ok(internalId);
}
```

But the `internalId` just gets `Guid.Empty`. - could anyone tell me where I went wrong (or a better way to do this)?

---

Or as another option is it possible for me to have a very typical controller:

```
[HttpGet("{internalId}")]
public IActionResult GetAccountId(Guid internalId)
{        
    return Ok(internalId);
}
```

And somehow write some middleware which does the transformation

```
app.MapGet("{externalid}", async context => {
   
   var externalId = context.GetRouteValue("externalId");
   // Here is the Guid I'm trying to pass to the controller.
   var internalId = await _externalService.GetInternalId(externalId);

   // redirect to my controller with internalId
});
```

Comment: Have you check your filter what did you get while calling that method?

Comment: The filter all works, but the `internalId` in the Controller is set to `default(Guid)` (ie `Guid.Empty`)

Comment: With `var internalId` we cannot see the type of `internalId` (missing debugging details here)

Comment: @JHBonarius It's a Guid. Its the thing im trying to pass to the controller argument

Comment: Shouldn't `[HttpGet("{externalCustomerId}", Name = "GetAccountId")]` be `[HttpGet("{internalId}", Name = "GetAccountId")]`? Else it's not the "route"

Comment: That's what im trying to avoid - I want the route to be `externalId` - do some transfomation, and receive `internalId` in the controller method.

Comment: Ok, but how should ASP.Net then know it should get the parameter from the route? I mean, you have to tell it where to get the data from. Wouldn't it be easier to change the value of `externalId`?

Comment: ASP.NET doesnt, _I do_ which is why im trying to write code to redirect a route value and not telling asp.net the route value. I think you might be missing the point of what im trying to do.

Comment: No, I can see what you are trying to do, but I'm questioning your expectations. ASP.Net can only do so much: if you want a parameter to be deducted from the route, it has to be specified in the route deduction path of the method. You could try adding the [`[FromRoute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute, to help ASP.Net, but it might not work.

Comment: It doesnt, but yep. I might just not be doing something sensible. Just trying to avoid having to do the same thing on almost every API endpoint

Answer (score -1):

You could use [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) to handle the conversion that way you only have to implement it once and then send it along

```
public class ExternalServiceHandler : IRequestHandler<ConvertExternalIdRequest, Guid>
{
  private readonly ExternalService _externalService;
  public ExternalServiceHandler(ExternalService externalService)
  {
    _externalService = externalService;
  }
  public Task<Guid> Handle(ConvertExternalIdRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    return Task.FromResult(_externalService.GetInternalId(request.ExternalId));
  }
}

public class ConvertExternalIdRequest : IRequest<Guid>
{
  public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalService
{
  public Guid GetInternalId(Guid externalId)
  {
    //do something
    return Guid.NewGuid();
  }
}
```

Or use [automapper](https://automapper.org/) to get the conversion. I've never injected anything into the profile before but I don't see why you couldn't

```
public class ExternalIdProfile : Profile
{
  private readonly ExternalService _externalService;
  public ExternalIdProfile(ExternalService externalService) 
  {
    CreateMap<ExternalEntity, InternalEntity>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.InternalId, 
      opt => opt.MapFrom(src => externalService.GetInternalId(src.ExternalId)));
  }
}

public class ExternalService
{
  public Guid GetInternalId(Guid externalId)
  {
    //do something
    return Guid.NewGuid();
  }
}

public class ExternalEntity
{
  public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }
}

public class InternalEntity
{
  public Guid InternalId { get; set; }
}
```